# Login and Index page, same url, htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a login like this:

```
www.mysite.com/login
```

and an index page like this (acting as a home page)

```
www.mysite.com
```

How can I make the login and the index have the same `URL` with `htaccess` ? -> `www.mysite.com`

**UPDATE NOTE:**

If my user is logged in go to `index.php` page = `www.mysite.com` url

If my user is not logged in go to `login.php` page = `www.mysite.com` url

Answer (score 0):

Very simple should be like this

```
DirectoryIndex login/ index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: wait I think I mislead my question

Comment: please re check it

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?section=([a-z0-9]+)&title=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1&title=$2 [L,NC]
```

this shoud be added to your .htaccess

and your project will become one page to direct the links which is index.php

you see this in the htaccess code  `(index.php?section=$1&title=$2)`

it will take the links and send it as parameters

for example `www.yoursite.com/login`    means `index.php?section=login`

and from you php file

type this

```
<?php 


if ($GET['section'] == "login"){

// include your page
echo 'my login page';
}else{
echo 'error 404';
}
```

hope you got it

Answer (score 0):

i got your question my friend

you can only make it by the sessions or cookies

so if the user logged in you should have create a sessions by php

for example

```
<?php
// Start the session in every page you will use it
session_start();

// when log-in is happen you give SESSION this 
$_SESSION["user_logged"] = "ture";

//then to check if hes logged or not 
if ($_SESSION["user_logged"] == "ture";){

echo'put your member page here';

}else{
echo'put your loging stuff here';
}

?>
```

Comment: sorry but I have 2 diff files, login.php and index.php

Comment: you have to use include then with if statement http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Comment: but fist follow this answer do the session and make it include the files